# Reaching elements of array of structures in assemby

Tags: assembly, struct, x86, masm, irvine32

The code that I wrote is here:

```
    TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)

Description:

Revision date:

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc   
INCLUDE macros.inc   
Employee STRUCT   
idnum BYTE "0000",0   
lastname BYTE 30 DUP(0)   
years WORD 0   
Employee ENDS    

.data   
workers Employee 3 DUP(<>)   
count DWORD ?   
.code   
main PROC

mov ecx,LENGTHOF workers
mov esi,TYPE Employee

l1:
mov count,ecx
mWrite "Enter employee id:> "

mov edx,OFFSET workers[esi].idnum
mov ecx,LENGTHOF workers.idnum
call ReadString
call crlf
mov ecx,count
add esi,TYPE employee
loop l1


exit
main ENDP

END main
```

I want to add `idnum` for every employee in the struct. How can I reach the `idnum` variable?

```
Here's the solution.
mov edx, OFFSET workers
add edx, esi
mov ecx, sizeof (employee ptr[edx]).idnum
call ReadString
```

Comment: Should be at `workers`, `workers + 36` and `workers + 72`. I don't know how Masm does it - `sizeof Employee`?

Comment: @FrankKotler yes you're right.i asked this question to my instructor today.he resolved this frustrating problem.I add the solution to first post.